# Horizontal ProgressBar not showing right

Tags: android, progress-bar

I created an XML file containing a horizontal ProgressBar, but it displays as in the image below:

[image: Progress bar image]

Here's my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="50" />

</LinearLayout>
```

What is happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: did you get your progressBar work now? see my answer

Comment: @K_Anas [here's your fix result](http://no6.upanh.com/b5.s28.d3/d92f828109ac5018216887c3680f635a_46596036.capture.png
)

Comment: Try adding `android:maxHeight="12dip" and android:minHeight="12dip"` to the progress bar.

Comment: @Chandra : it's smaller but not change

Answer (score 1):

Normally you should get an horizontalProgress bar with your layout but try to

change your style tag in your ProgressBar widget to this

```
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"


<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="50" />
```

Comment: i had changed style but it not change

Comment: @user1465351 try to clear your project!! or event restart eclipse, and let me know

Answer (score 0):

It's being warped to the size you gave it in

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

Try using wrap_content or set a layout_weight. Also, it seems you don't have a very good understanding of XML layouts.  I recommend perusing this article: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Comment: i try it (wrapcontent and fillparent or fix size) but not work. I also cleaned and build but it not work

Comment: I think the guy above me understood you better.

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest add this in Activity file

```
pbSurvey.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#0668A1"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to add a android:indeterminate="false" to your XML file? Your progress bar XML should look like this:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:max="100"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:progress="50" />
```

The spinning wheel is for "indeterminate" mode, when the total progress is not known (i.e. you're just letting the user know that they need to wait, but you're not sure how long for).